# Get clicked button properties in Context Menu Android

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have a custom view which has a button in it, There is no ListView or GridView Involved. I am opening a context menu by long pressing on this button, Context Menu is opening fine, I am able to get menu item select click events as well. I just want to get access of the button clicked inside the context menu item select event, I just want the text of the button which was long pressed to open the context menu.

Button Code:

```
btnContext = view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
btnContext.setText("I want this text");
registerForContextMenu(btnContext);
```

onCreateContextMenu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, final View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
 super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Option1");
 menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Option2");
}
```

onContextItemSelected:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

//  I want to log btnContext text here. 

}
```

Comment: I think you are creating option menu in a wrong way. refer here: https://github.com/andor201995/NoteIt/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/andor/navigate/notepad/listing/fragment/NoteListingFragment.kt#L57

Comment: I have posted simplified code, as I mentioned my context menu is working, just need to access the button which opened the context menu

Comment: The simplest thing to do would probably be to keep a `private View` field, and assign that the `View` parameter in `onCreateContextMenu()`, as that parameter is the `View` that the context menu is being created for.